# How to suppress "Line too long" warning (pyright-extended) in Replit Python?

Tags: python, suppress-warnings, replit, ruff

When coding in Python using [Replit](https://replit.com/%7E), I get the annoying warning "Line too long" (pyright-extended).

[image]

How can I get Replit to always ignore displaying this type of warnings?

Comment: FYI, [`pyright-extended`](https://github.com/replit/pyright-extended) is a mixture of [Pyright](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright), [YAPF](https://github.com/google/yapf) and [Ruff](https://github.com/astral-sh/ruff) which was made by Replit. Pyright itself doesn't do this kind of linting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `'E501'` to the "[tool.ruff]" section of the "**pyproject.toml**"-file, to disable the warning in the default python template.

[image: pyproject.toml]

https://ask.replit.com/t/python-88-characters-maximum-in-a-line/74941